# Does hd-idle check if the disk is idle prior to spin down the drive?

Tags: debian, hard-disk, smartctl, hdparm, hd-idle

I was thinking about to let `hd-idle` manage the spin down of all my drives after 3 hours because I am having trouble doing so with `hdparm` or `smartctl` in conjunction with apm or sleep command.

---

So my question is: Does HD-Idle check if the disk is in use or idle prior to send it to sleep?

And in case it does not: Do you have a nice solution or script that I can copy / modify to my needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `hd-idle` keeps track of disk activity and only spins a disk down if it hasn’t had any activity for the configured idle period. It does this by keeping track of changes to `/proc/diskstats` for the disks it’s configured to handle.